# What is "Bardem será nominado para los Oscar" in the active voice?

Tags: gramática, voz-pasiva

How would the sentence "Sin duda Bardem será nominado de nuevo para los Oscar" be rewritten in the active voice? In English I can't even think what it would be.

Comment: The key to this type of problem is that if there is no subject jumping out at you, you have to make one up.  "Bardem will be nominated by some movie critics" *does* give you a subject, do you see?  But "Bardem will be nominated" doesn't.  But to make an active sentence **you have to have a subject** -- so it's up to you to supply it.  Once you have that, it will be smooth sailing -- just find the main verb and conjugate it.  That gives you the basic structure of the sentence and you can fill in the bits and pieces.

Answer (score 3):

Just as in English:

- The Academy / They will nominate Bardem for the Oscars.

we can also say in Spanish:

- La Academia nominará / Nominarán a Bardem para los Oscar.